# get response of grape endpoint with def after

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape

I'm using Grape. I want to define a method that runs after the response value has been calculated for a request, I tried following this:

http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters

and ended up with:

```
after do
  puts response
end
```

however response is not defined. Apparently within this block, `self` refers to `Grape::Endpoint`, since after runs after the endpoint handler, I should be able to find the response value, right? I tried `self.body` however this returns nothing - it does, however, let me change the value of the response, but I want to retrieve the response value that was generated by my handler.

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, so I solved this using rack middleware:

```
class CaptureResponse < Grape::Middleware::Base
    def call!(env)
        @env = env
        @app_response = @app.call(@env)
        body = @app_response[2]
        body = body.body if body.kind_of? Rack::BodyProxy
        puts body
        @app_response
    end
end
use CaptureResponse
```

I have no idea why just slapping in `use CaptureResponse` in config.ru works but it does!